# VueJs anchor tag relative path is not working in my system

Tags: html, vue.js

I use relative path in the VueJs and used as a-tag, but it is not clickable on my system, while the same code is work on the other system. Below is the path created with anchor tag.

```
<div class="mr-auto ft-14"><a v-on:click="showDetail(data.item)">{{ data.item.name }}</a></div>
```

Here I using Mozilla and Chromes both and its output is not clickable.

[image: Output Link is unable to click while it is clickable on other systems]

Comment: You have to add href property in a tag to make it clickable i guess.

Comment: Also, try removing classes -- may be CSS is affected.

Comment: With same property and classes it is working on other system. Is it is possible or probable problem in my system? If yes what need to do?